# Convert Object to Byte Array

Tags: xamarin.ios

Edit :

Sorry for the late response.

I tried the code  in the answer ,but I had a problem with the conversion from Byte to Image .

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            var image = UIImage.FromFile("image.png");

            var imageWidth = image.Size.Width;
            var imageHeight = image.Size.Height;

            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            var fullfilename = Path.Combine(documents, "Image.json");

            // save json methode

            SaveImageJson(image, fullfilename);

            // read json methode

            var newImage = readImageJson(fullfilename, imageWidth, imageHeight);


        }


        public static void SaveImageJson(UIImage image, string fullfilename)
        {
            // Convert image to byteArray

            Byte[] imageByteArray = ReadFully(image.AsPNG().AsStream());


            // Serialize object
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageByteArray, Formatting.Indented);

            // Save to file

            File.WriteAllText(fullfilename, json);
        }

        public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static UIImage readImageJson(string fullfilename, nfloat width, nfloat height)
        {

            var filenameNewImage = File.ReadAllText(fullfilename, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

            var jsonNewImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(filenameNewImage);

            Byte[] ByteNewImage = ObjectToByteArray(jsonNewImage);


            UIImage NewImage = new UIImage();

            NewImage = ImageFromBytes(ByteNewImage, width, height);

            return NewImage;

        }


        public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private static UIImage ImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes, nfloat width, nfloat height)
        {
            try
            {
                NSData data = NSData.FromArray(bytes);
                UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                CGSize scaleSize = new CGSize(width, height);
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(scaleSize, false, 0);
                image.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, scaleSize.Width, scaleSize.Height));
                UIImage resizedImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
                return resizedImage;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I have a problem converting an Object to a Byte Array

I have a Xamarin.IOS simulation in which I have to read the data which is an image that i saved before using the Json method . I have a problem while reading my data back and I think it has a relation with the conversion . I used a method to convert the object that I get from the Json file to an Byte Array, so I can convert that later to an UIImage , unfortunately the conversion doesn't work because when I compare the Byte Array I saved and the one I got from method read , I found out that they are different

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad(); 
  // getting the file that we saved the data before

      var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "account.json");
        File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
    var filename2 = File.ReadAllText(filename,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

        var json2 = ObjectToByteArray(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(filename2));


        NSData data2 = NSData.FromArray(json2);

        UIImage image2 = new UIImage();
        image2 = UIImage.LoadFromData(data2);

        img.Image = image2;

    }

    public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you just needing to write/read image data from a file?  Or does it really need to be serialized as json?  If so, how are you serializing the data in the first place?

Comment: I think json can not be directly converted to show image.If want json to byte array , I will show it.

Comment: Hi , I modified my question so you can have more details about the problem. I would like json to byte array first

Comment: @HichamHassani Thanks for updating question.I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use another conversion.

First of all, convert your UIImage to Stream. To do it use 'myUIImage.AsPng().AsStream()'. Then convert 'Stream' to 'Byte Array'. To do so use:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can safely serialize it.

To make Image from Byte Array you can use this extension

```
private UIImage ImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes, nfloat width, nfloat height)
{
    try {
        NSData data = NSData.FromArray(bytes);
        UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
        CGSize scaleSize = new CGSize(width, height);
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(scaleSize, false, 0);
        image.Draw(new CGRect(0,0, scaleSize.Width, scaleSize.Height));
        UIImage resizedImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return resizedImage;
    } catch (Exception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Believe this will be helpful.

Comment: Hi , I've tried what you wrote and it didn't work , I've updated my original question